# Microbenchmark showing process-switching faster than thread-switching; what's wrong?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, benchmarking

I have two simple microbenchmarks trying to measure thread- and process-switching overheads, but the process-switching overhead is turning out to be *lower* than that of thread-switching, which is unexpected. The setup: 1.8GHz Core 2 Duo, 2GB RAM, Linux 2.6.32-21-generic x86_64 (Ubuntu 10.04). I'm getting:

- ~2.1-2.4us per process switch
- ~4us per thread switch

I tried also running with `numactl --physcpubind=0` and `likwid-pin -c0`, but this seemed to only slow down the thread switches to 5us. Anybody know what's wrong with the evaluation, or if these results are right why they are?

The code is living at the URLs below, and r1667 is pasted here:

https://assorted.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/assorted/sandbox/trunk/src/c/process_switch_bench.c

```
// on zs, ~2.1-2.4us/switch

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

uint32_t COUNTER;
pthread_mutex_t LOCK;
pthread_mutex_t START;
sem_t *s0, *s1, *s2;

void * threads (
    void * unused
) {
    // Wait till we may fire away
    sem_wait(s2);

    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&LOCK);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&LOCK);
        COUNTER++;
        sem_post(s0);
        sem_wait(s1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int64_t timeInMS ()
{
    struct timeval t;

    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    return (
        (int64_t)t.tv_sec * 1000 +
        (int64_t)t.tv_usec / 1000
    );
}

int main (
    int argc,
    char ** argv
) {
    int64_t start;
    pthread_t t1;

    pthread_mutex_init(&LOCK, NULL);

    COUNTER = 0;
    s0 = sem_open("/s0", O_CREAT, 0022, 0);
    if (s0 == 0) { perror("sem_open"); exit(1); }
    s1 = sem_open("/s1", O_CREAT, 0022, 0);
    if (s1 == 0) { perror("sem_open"); exit(1); }
    s2 = sem_open("/s2", O_CREAT, 0022, 0);
    if (s2 == 0) { perror("sem_open"); exit(1); }

    int x, y, z;
    sem_getvalue(s0, &x);
    sem_getvalue(s1, &y);
    sem_getvalue(s2, &z);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
      pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threads, NULL);
      pthread_detach(t1);
      // Get start time and fire away
      start = timeInMS();
      sem_post(s2);
      sem_post(s2);

      // Wait for about a second
      sleep(1);
      // Stop thread
      pthread_mutex_lock(&LOCK);

      // Find out how much time has really passed. sleep won't guarantee me that
      // I sleep exactly one second, I might sleep longer since even after being
      // woken up, it can take some time before I gain back CPU time. Further
      // some more time might have passed before I obtained the lock!
      int64_t time = timeInMS() - start;
      // Correct the number of thread switches accordingly
      COUNTER = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)COUNTER * 2 * 1000) / time);
      printf("Number of process switches in about one second was %u\n", COUNTER);
      printf("roughly %f microseconds per switch\n", 1000000.0 / COUNTER);

      // clean up
      kill(pid, 9);
      wait(0);
      sem_close(s0);
      sem_close(s1);
      sem_unlink("/s0");
      sem_unlink("/s1");
      sem_unlink("/s2");
    } else {
      if (1) { sem_t *t = s0; s0 = s1; s1 = t; }
      threads(0); // never return
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://assorted.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/assorted/sandbox/trunk/src/c/thread_switch_bench.c

```
// From <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304752/how-to-estimate-the-thread-context-switching-overhead>

// on zs, ~4-5us/switch; tried making COUNTER updated only by one thread, but no difference

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

uint32_t COUNTER;
pthread_mutex_t LOCK;
pthread_mutex_t START;
pthread_cond_t CONDITION;

void * threads (
    void * unused
) {
    // Wait till we may fire away
    pthread_mutex_lock(&START);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&START);
    int first=1;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&LOCK);
    // If I'm not the first thread, the other thread is already waiting on
    // the condition, thus Ihave to wake it up first, otherwise we'll deadlock
    if (COUNTER > 0) {
        pthread_cond_signal(&CONDITION);
        first=0;
    }
    for (;;) {
        if (first) COUNTER++;
        pthread_cond_wait(&CONDITION, &LOCK);
        // Always wake up the other thread before processing. The other
        // thread will not be able to do anything as long as I don't go
        // back to sleep first.
        pthread_cond_signal(&CONDITION);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&LOCK);
    return 0;
}

int64_t timeInMS ()
{
    struct timeval t;

    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    return (
        (int64_t)t.tv_sec * 1000 +
        (int64_t)t.tv_usec / 1000
    );
}


int main (
    int argc,
    char ** argv
) {
    int64_t start;
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;

    pthread_mutex_init(&LOCK, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&START, NULL);   
    pthread_cond_init(&CONDITION, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&START);
    COUNTER = 0;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threads, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, threads, NULL);
    pthread_detach(t1);
    pthread_detach(t2);
    // Get start time and fire away
    start = timeInMS();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&START);
    // Wait for about a second
    sleep(1);
    // Stop both threads
    pthread_mutex_lock(&LOCK);
    // Find out how much time has really passed. sleep won't guarantee me that
    // I sleep exactly one second, I might sleep longer since even after being
    // woken up, it can take some time before I gain back CPU time. Further
    // some more time might have passed before I obtained the lock!
    int64_t time = timeInMS() - start;
    // Correct the number of thread switches accordingly
    COUNTER = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)COUNTER * 2 * 1000) / time);
    printf("Number of thread switches in about one second was %u\n", COUNTER);
    printf("roughly %f microseconds per switch\n", 1000000.0 / COUNTER);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Linux only schedules threads. There is likely something else going on here. I would suggest using ftrace which will help pinpoint where the extra time is being taken.

Comment: The Linux scheduler may only schedule threads, but shouldn't processes take longer than threads to switch between because of address-space switching, TLB shootdowns & reload, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: pthread_mutex_lock() takes around about 2ms on your system, and your threads version takes two locks each time through the loop, whereas the processes version takes only one lock.

Comment: Actually, it's the process-switching benchmark which is touching more synchronization structures; the thread version is only interacting with one lock/CV. (I've confusingly left the name unchanged -- the main loop is in a threads() function in both programs.)

Answer (score 0):

Historically Unix (and Linux as it derivative) had relatively cheap `fork()` so process creating wasn't an issue and concurrent processesing was (and still mostly is) done using multiple processes.

Later other OSes appeared (don't want to call names) that were very heavy on process creation so people working on those had to invent threads, which very "light" processes, thus introduced the whole new bunch of concurrency problems.

UNIX/Linux world followed the suit by introducing threads as well, although there wasn't really a need. However support for threads in Linux is somewhat limited - threads for the one process must share one core, so in many cases multi-process environment on Linux is faster than multi-threaded, which is likely the reason for the result you've got.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I'm actually already aware of the history here, of the high-level overhead differences, and of the pains of shared-memory concurrent programming. My question still stands, though. It also is very much not true that threads of a process are pinned to the same core.

Comment: Ok I was incorrect about limited support for threads in CFS, but if I remember correctly, if you don't specify CPU affinity for the thread explicitly, it will use the same CPU/core. The idea probably was to minimise cache misses, but as a result threads of one process tend to be bound to the same core